# Should "questions" advertising for jobs be flagged as spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

I recently ran into [this "question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170957/paid-consultation-need-to-engage-gpu-on-windows-ce-6-0-device), which is currently collecting downvotes and close votes, that's basically a job listing.

Image for under 10k:

[image]

I guess it's not *technically* promoting a product or service, but it absolutely exists solely for the purpose of promoting their job. And it's not like they couldn't just buy a job ad if that's what they're looking to do.

Should stuff like this be flagged as spam?